# Remote Python Bot: Push Notifications throughout the day

Tags: python, server, bots, remote-server

Preface: I'm new to programming. I searched extensively for info on this idea and couldn't find anything that seemed right. Most likely, I just don't know how to frame my question.

Q: I want to run code/script/bot on a server/machine other than my own(So I don't have to leave my PC on). The code will scrape data (say weather), and send it via sms/email/etc. to my phone throughout the day.

This is likely very simple, but I am having difficulty framing the problem and asking the right questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific tool you're having trouble implementing? Asking for recommendations or broad guidance is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: @Jay I tried very hard to search for information on this site and all over google, but I really can't figure this out. I just want to host a bot on a machine other than my own so it can stay running continuously. I wish I could be more specific, but I'm just working backwards from my idea.